# How to access windows username and domain name (from Active Directory) through Chrome 2021

Tags: windows, google-chrome, active-directory

I have read articles on getting windows username and domain name from chrome, one api is npapi and it is deprecated now. I also saw javascript is not an option because obviously if it is allowed, then it is a huge security risk. Is there anyway to do this in Chrome?

Comment: @marc_s maybe you are interested in a solution, I added and answer!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as I though there is no direct way of doing that. But I managed to find a way through selenium web driver. so simply I create a web driver and write values to the chrome's local storage via java:

```
    WebDriverManager.getInstance(ChromeDriver.class).setup();
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://yourapp_url");
    LocalStorage local = ((WebStorage) driver).getLocalStorage();
    local.setItem("win_domain", System.getenv().get("USERDOMAIN"));
    local.setItem("win_username", System.getenv().get("USERNAME"));
```

and pom goes:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>WindowsChromeLauncher</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-alpha-7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-devtools-v86</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-alpha-7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>SeleniumLocalStorage</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

you will need to run this command and create an executable jar:
mvn clean compile assembly:single